# my jquery plugin has the wrong scope

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to write a simple plugin, enterkeypress, which extends the keypress event, but only fires when the key pressed is the enter key:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.enterkeypress = function (fn) {
    return this.keypress(function(event){
      if(event.which == '13'){
        event.preventDefault();
        fn();
        }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

when testing this out, it correctly fires the event but the 'this' keyword references the window, not the element.

```
$(":text").enterkeypress(function(){console.log(this)});
```

that code will output Window in the console... I'd rather it output the input control.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fn callback parameter being passed is still called using the global scope which is window.
You should use either **call or apply** to execute fn using the jquery objects context.

Try this:

```
 (function ($) {
      $.fn.enterkeypress = function (fn) {
        return this.keypress(function(event){
          if(event.which == '13'){
            event.preventDefault();
           //#####NOTICE THE CHANGE HERE###.
            fn.call(this);
            }
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [call or apply](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=829) on the callback to alter the this reference:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.enterkeypress = function (fn) {
    return this.keypress(function(event){
      if(event.which == '13'){
        event.preventDefault();
        fn.apply(this);
        }
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```